# only Show content after paypal payment successful

Tags: php, paypal

i'm not a php guy :(

I hope someone would help me with this.

I have created a paypal buy button and have set advance redirect to websiteurl/cancel if payment is failed, and also set redirect to websiteurl/success, and i just want to show the content of websiteurl/success if the payment is successful and if someone sends the websiteurl/success link to another user the content will not be shown or maybe a note will be posted like please purchase our product to download..

what codes do i need to have on my websiteurl/success page to only show the downloadable content if the payment was made and not to show it to another user that didn't made the content,, i have seen paypal digital goods but the setup is too complicated for me..:(

for example my websiteurl/success page contains just 2 div

```
<div id="download">
Thank you for your purchase...
<a href="filelocationurl" class="button">DOWNLOAD NOW!</a>
</div>

<div id="notpaid">Please Purchase our product to download</div>
```

God bless

Comment: You'll want to look into PayPal's IPN. https://www.paypal.com/ipn -- There are many php Paypal IPN classes out there, to start here's PayPal's example https://cms.paypal.com/cms_content/CA/en_US/files/developer/IPN_PHP_41.txt -- More info at http://paypal.github.io/sample-apps/

Answer (score 2):

You can either use a 3rd party shopping cart that is set up to specifically handle digital goods.  A list of digital goods shopping carts can be found [here](https://cms.paypal.com/us/cgi-bin/?cmd=_render-content&content_ID=developer/solutions_dgd).

Another option would be to set up a return URL to have the buyer redirected back to after making a purchase.  For example, if you were selling one item you can create a buy now button from your account.  When you are creating this button, on the 3rd step of the button creation process you have an option to set a URL that you would like to have the buyer returned to after completing a successful payment, they would be redirected to this page and you can have the item available on this page for download.  However a buy now button will only allow the buyer to buy one item at a time.  If you use a add to cart button, then this method will not work as it will only use one of the return URL's that you try to set.  This is where you could use PDT and set your return page up to check to see what they ordered and display the correct links for all the items on the return page.

Another option would be to use IPN.  Instant Payment Notification (IPN) allows you to automate certain aspects of your business by posting transaction details to your server whenever you receive a PayPal payment or whenever a status change occurs on a transaction.   You could create a script that would sent the customer an email with either the link to where they can download the item at, or send the item to them as an attachment.  You would need to create a custom IPN script to do this, or have a web developer create this script for you.  If you are familiar with programming you can find more out about [IPN here](https://cms.paypal.com/us/cgi-bin/?&cmd=_render-content&content_ID=developer/e_howto_admin_IPNIntro).

Answer (score -1):

Set a session cookie called "payment-success" to false. After the payment, set your cookie to true. Then,

```
    if ($_SESSION['payment-success'] == true) {
            echo '<p>Please Purchase our product to download</p>';
    }else{
        echo '<p>Thank you for your purchase...</p><br>';
        echo '<a href="filelocationurl" class="button">DOWNLOAD NOW!</a>';
    }
```

You're welcome.